# Revel template multiple variables, access one inside the others range

Tags: html, go, revel

I have a controller passing two variables

```
func (a App) Page() revel.Result {
    var g []*G
    ...
    return c.Render(p, g)
}
```

in my `.html` I want to iterate over `g`. Is it possible to access p inside the iteration? I couldnt manage. My try looks like the following

```
{{range .g}}
... // print g related stuff
.p
{{end}}
```

and it throws `can't evaluate field p in type *G`.

Comment: Isn't `p` the name of the template file?

Comment: @TheHippo tried to clearify that. It should render `Page` right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revel seems to be using Go's template engine, therefore I guess you should be able to use whatever stuff's allowed with `html/template` like variables.

```
{{$p := .p}}
{{range .g}}
... // print g related stuff
{{$p}}
{{end}}
```

See documentation for more info https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables

<strike>Please note, if `p` is not a key in a map but a field of a struct, you won't be able to access it, i believe, since it is not exported.</strike> Ok I understand now, Revel seems to derive the names inside the template from the names of the arguments that were passed to `Render`.